# Can we do patch releases in google app engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I'm doing a google app engine related and I want know that if we can do patch release in GAE. I simply want change a js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your app any time you like. You can either override the existing version, or create a new version of your app. Then you can specify which version is default in App Engine console for your project.

The deployment process only uploads the files that you have changed.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, But the thing is we are having a problem of not deploying the whole app, we just want to do a patch release.

Comment: The deployment process will only upload the files that you have changed.